# logrotate apache errors and send to email

Tags: linux, apache, logrotate

can anyone please tell me how to use the logrotate command to send me daily emails with the apache logs?

I cant really find an example like I want

thank you

Comment: I had something similar that I wanted to accomplish and found this tutorial helpful: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/rotate-apache-logs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how to use logrotate for this, but it is quite easy to write shell script that archives latest log and sends it to you over e-mail, and then to put this script into crontab.

Comment: any idea how? I am unexperienced in linux